# How to derivate the following loss function?

Tags: regression, optimization, loss-functions, gradient-descent, derivative

How can I derivate the following optimization function?

$$L=\sum_{u,i}(y_{u,i}-v_ix_u)^2+\lambda\left(\sum_i\|v_i\|_2^2+\sum_u\|x_u\|_2^2\right)$$

I just want to get the equations of the gradient descent method, so I want to get the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $v$ and the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $x$.

I just know how to calculate the first of the term of the function, but I have trouble to derive the second addend of the function:

$$\delta v_i^k L=-2\sum_i(y_{u,i}-v_i x_u)x_u^k + ¿?$$
$$\delta x_i^k L=-2\sum_i(y_{u,i}-v_i x_u)v_u^k + ¿?$$

Comment: You mention partial derivatives regarding $u$, but there is no $u$ in the expression

Comment: Thanks! I mean x. Sorry for the misstake.

Comment: If you're uncertain about vector notation, you might be able to make headway by re-writing it in terms of scalar products and sums.

Comment: What's the nature of $v_i$ and $x_u$? I take it they are vectors, but their product would be incompatible. Is $y_{u,i}$ a scalar?

Comment: Both the v_i and the x_u are vectors. You cant consider that y_{u,i} ~ x_u v_i

Comment: But if both are column, or row, vectors, then they have incompatible dimensions and you can't compute $v_ix_u$

Comment: Both v and x have the same dimension, does it fix the problems?

Comment: Does this thing have an interpretation? You have the regression tag, and it would look like ridge regression if not for the sum of norms of $x$s.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada you are missing a transpose, in either $x_u$ or $v_i$, depending on if the result should be a matrix or a scalar

Comment: Sorry guys, I just said incorrectly the purpose of the question. I want to calculate the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $v$ and the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $x$

Comment: @Firebug I have updated the original post in order to focus the problem that I have

Comment: But you still didn't respond. I think you are missing a transpose in either $x_u$ or $v_i$, depending on if $y_{u,i}$ is a scalar or a matrix. The matrix product $x_uv_i$ does not exist for equal sized vectors, whereas the products $x_u^Tv_i$ and $x_uv_i^T$ do.

Comment: @Sycorax can you (or someone else) reopen this one? I'll answer it to help OP out

Comment: @Firebug I've up-voted your previous comment because I agree that the notation is unclear. It doesn't appear to me that the lack of clarity has been removed. How do you know what the vector product represents?

Comment: @Sycorax I'm led to believe it's a row-vector/column-vector matrix product, because $y_{u,i}$ would be scalar so the $L_2$ norm is analogue to Ridge regression, as OP mentioned. If $y_{u,i}$ was a matrix we'd be talking in terms of a matrix norm, and I don't believe that to be the case here.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezLosada I've rolled back your most recent edit because it removed the very expression you wished to differentiate. Without it, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Did I answer your question @CarlosVázquezLosada? By the way, is this about compressed-sensing?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the long comment chain under OP, assuming $y_{u,i}$ is scalar, $v_i$ is a row vector and $x_u$ is a column vector (with matching sizes), we can show that:

$$L=\sum_{u,i}(y_{u,i}-v_ix_u)^2+\lambda\left(\sum_i\|v_i\|_2^2+\sum_u\|x_u\|_2^2\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_a}
=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_a}\left\{\sum_{i}(y_{a,i}-v_ix_a)^2+\lambda\|x_a\|_2^2\right\}\\
=\frac{\partial }{\partial x_a}\left\{\sum_{i}(y_{a,i}-v_ix_a)^2\right\}+\lambda\frac{\partial }{\partial x_a}\left\{\|x_a\|_2^2\right\}\\
=-2\sum_{i}(y_{a,i}-v_ix_a)v_i^T+2\lambda x_a\\
$$

By similar analogy

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v_j}
=-2\sum_{u}(y_{u,j}-v_jx_u)x_u^T+2\lambda v_j\\
$$

Notice that both gradients were assumed (by me) to have the same dimensions of the parameters.
Bar any error, you were missing only the derivative of the squared $\ell_2$ norm of a vector. This can be simply be shown to be, for vector $w$ (irrespective of the nature of $w$, be it a column or row matrix).

$$\frac{\partial \|w\|_2^2}{\partial w}=2w$$

Addendum: if you take vector derivatives to have a specific configuration, e.g. always rows or always columns, then some adjustments are due. Since you did not assume vectors to be column matrices (as we can see by the vector product), I think my solution is on point.